# Getting scrolltop value from absolute positioned element with overflow set to scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, css-position, scrolltop

I am using an absolute positioned body element to prevent the "bouncy" scroll-behavior in mac os. This way its not the window that is scrolled but the body element which doesnt "bounce".

But now the scrollTop() value is always 0.

I need to know how much I have scrolled the body element. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/hbJWn/

Edit: It seems to work in Mac OS X Firefox 13.0.
But doesn't in Mac OS X Chrome 19. Seems to be a webkit issue, Safari also doenst work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could put a *wrapper* `<div>` directly inside the body, and put all other content *within* that wrapper.

Eg,

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
     <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Then, on $('body').scroll(),  instead of looking at $('body').scrollTop(), you could consider the offset position of that wrapper:  $('#wrapper').position().top

I modified your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bT9fV/1/

Seems to work OK in Chrome 19

The offset position of that wrapper will give you basically the same information as the scrollTop() would, so I can't think of a reason this wouldn't suffice.